# Angular: How to override the shared module service from different module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have multiple modules say `SchoolModule`, `UniversityModule`, `SharedModule`

`SharedModule` has `BaseService` to which both `SchoolModule` and `UniversityModule` providers are extending

Now when I load my `SchoolModule`, I want `BaseService` should get the implementation of `schoolService`, and the same goes for `UniversityModule`

**Structure**

```
app
  -- SharedModule
       -- base.service
       -- secret.service uses base.service
       -- shared.component uses secret.service

  -- SchoolModule
       -- school.component uses shared.component
       -- school.service

 -- UniversityModule
        -- university.component uses shared.component
        -- university.service
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/injectiontoken-2098?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fsecret.service.ts)

So how I can achieve this with Dependency Injection?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your base service class as an abstract class with an abstract method getName()

```
export abstract class BaseService{


    abstract getName(): string { return 'Base Service' }


}

export class SchoolService extends BaseService{

   getName(): string { return 'School Service' }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Angular2 can not inject a class from another module without get the import between modules, and if you need to lazy load it, things do not work.
There is a project that load dynamically a component from another module.
It is difficult to import this in to your project, but saves you to not code twice.
This project can be found [here](https://github.com/devboosts/dynamic-component-loader).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SecretService provided is the one build with build in UniversityModule last imported module in App Module so if you want to have SecretService update with correctly BaseService you have to provide both BaseService and SecretService in university and school component something like this in school.component.ts:

```
import { SchoolService } from './school.service'
import { BaseService } from '../shared/base.service'
import { SecretService } from '../shared/secret.service'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-school',
      template: `SchoolName :: <app-shared></app-shared>`,
      providers: [
        { provide: BaseService, useClass: SchoolService },
        SecretService]
    })
    export class SchoolComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

and in university.component.ts

```
import {  UniversityService } from './university.service'
import { BaseService } from '../shared/base.service'
import { SecretService } from '../shared/secret.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-university',
  template: `UniversityName :: <app-shared></app-shared>`,
  providers: [{ provide: BaseService, useClass: UniversityService },
  SecretService]
})
export class UniversityComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

But why you wanna wrap base service in SecretService instead directly use BaseService in shared component ?

Using BaseService like this in shared.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseService } from './base.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-shared',
  template: `{{name}}`
})
export class SharedComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string
  constructor(private ss: BaseService) {
    this.name = ss.getName()
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Using BaseService you will solve this injection problem without any workaround on SecretService